# Run a Python function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I have some code written in python that uses PyAutoGui:

```
import pyautogui

def mult_choice(OPTION):
    if OPTION == 1:
        pyautogui.press('1')
    elif OPTION == 2:
        pyautogui.press('2')
    elif OPTION == 3:
        pyautogui.press('3')
    elif OPTION == 4:
        pyautogui.press('4')
    sleep(2)
```

I also plan to write some code in Javascript that will get the variable OPTION. As far as I know, you can't control the keyboard in Javascript, so I wrote that part in Python. However, I wasn't sure if it is possible to run a python function in a Javascript program. If this is possible, someone explaining it to me would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for node.js or client-side?

Comment: This is for node.js.

Comment: you can run python in node.js enviroment, there are npm packages that will do that for you, but i dont think you can run python in browser enviroment without something like we asembly, but i am not really familiar with it

Comment: The only way I know of to run python in node would be to spawn a child process, however it seems like you should be able to do what you want to do entirely in one language. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34974712/node-js-capture-keyboard-press-and-mouse-movement-not-on-web-browser) shows two different methods of capturing keyboard input in node.js

Comment: This question might help you with emitting keyboard events in JS: ["Node.js JavaScript: Simulate Keypress on Server (Like a Macro)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848747/node-js-javascript-simulate-keypress-on-server-like-a-macro)